# What's the difference between these regexes

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm reading Ionic's source code. I came across this regex, and i"m pretty baffled by it.

```
([\s\S]+?)
```

Ok, it's grouping on every char that is either a white space, or non white space???

Why didn't they just do

```
(.+?)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: because the dot doesn't match the newline character `\n`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `.` matches any symbol but a newline. In order to make it match a newline, in most languages there is a modifier (dotall, singleline). However, in JS, there is no such a modifier.

Thus, a work-around is to use a `[\s\S]` character class that will match any character, including a newline, because `\s` will match all whitespace and `\S` will match all non-whitespace characters. Similarly, one could use `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]`.

Also, there is a `[^]` pattern to match the same thing in JS, but since it is JavaScript-specific, the regexes containing this pattern are not portable between regex flavors.

The `+?` lazy quanitifier matches 1 or more symbols conforming to the preceding subpattern, but as few as possible. Thus, it will match just 1 symbol if used like this, at the end of the pattern.

Comment: Just for completeness: the *dotall/singleline* modifier is usually `s` in other flavors.

Comment: **Argh!** - `m` means something entirely different in other flavors (including JS)... Why didn't they just stick to `s`? :-\ Also they name it `Regexp::MULTILINE` which is not the same thing as, say, `PCRE2_MULTILINE`. Nice gotcha here. Principle of least astonishment you say? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A `.` matches everything *but* the newline character. This is actually a well known/documented problem with javascript. The `\s` (whitespace match) alongside it's negation `\S` (non-whitespace match) provides a `dotall` match including the newline. Thus `[\s\S]` is generally used more frequently than `.`

Answer (score 3):

In many realizations of Regexp "." doesn't match new lines. So they use "[\s\S]" as a little hack =)

Answer (score 1):

The RegEx they used includes more characters (essentially everything).

`\s` matches any word or digit character or whitespace.

`\S` matches anything except a digit, word character, or whitespace

As Casimir notes:

`.` matches any character except newline (`\n`)

Answer (score 1):

`.` matches any char except carriage return `/r` and new line `/n`

The Shortest way to do `[/s/S]`(white space and non white space) is `[^]`(not nothing)